# In the context of Operating Systems, why is an atomic instruction like testAndSet needed to implement a mutex?

Tags: operating-system

I also have a few additional questions: What are some of the problems with busy waiting, and in what circumstances is it okay/appropriate to use busy waiting? Is there an alternative to busy waiting?

Comment: Because if test and set are not atomic, then someone may set the lock in the middle of your testing of the lock's position and setting of the lock's position.

Answer (score 2):

> In the context of Operating Systems, why is an atomic instruction like testAndSet needed to implement a mutex?

It's required because generally a given thread of execution does not know when it could have its execution halted. Suppose you had to perform a check machine instruction followed by the set machine instruction. It is possible(although potentially the chance of it happening small) that after doing the "check" instruction the core takes an interrupt, the kernel switches to a second thread and that thread runs the check and set instructions on the same mutex. Now when the original thread continues it thinks it can take the mutex owing to having passed the "check" instruction, runs the "set" instruction and now we have two threads running inside the mutually excluded code which very likely could crash your program or kernel! However, if the "set and check" instruction is performed atomically, we don't have to worry about getting caught in this situation.

Additionally, some architectures atomic set instructions also are tied into ensuring that the changes are propagated through the various caches correctly and efficiently so that other cores can access the same mutex.

> What are some of the problems with busy waiting
>
> Is there an alternative to busy waiting?

The main issue is that while a core is busy waiting, no forward progress can be made by other threads. To get around this the scheduler for the OS can stop the execution of the thread waiting on the mutex and let another thread run. When the mutex is released the scheduler can then resume execution of the thread that blocked on the mutex.

> in what circumstances is it okay/appropriate to use busy waiting

Sometimes when the mutex is held only for a short duration it's better to busy wait for the mutex to become free then switch execution to another thread. This mostly owes to the fact that context switching (jumping execution to a different thread), can be a time consuming process. If the mutex is held for a short enough duration, the time spent context switching will be more than that that of just busy waiting.